# Correct syntax on isset function PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, isset

```
 //I want to check "adjustBtn'. $item_id.'" if it is set
     <input name="adjustBtn' . $item_id . '" type="submit" value="change" />

  //I tried all syntax but no luck 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'] , $_post["$item_id"] )){
```

this is my code. What Im trying to achieve is to check if the button is set. My problem is I dont know the right syntax for isset function help me please

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: If you are really asking about syntax, then the [php.net Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) should give you more than enough information. If you are asking about something not covered by the manual, try to be more specific and clear on what is it about.

Comment: $_POST is not equal to $_post

Comment: `$item_id` from where you are getting this. Is this value fixed?

Comment: dont know y r using id in button name, so u can use like `if(isset($_POST['adjustBtn'.$item_id])){`

Answer (score 0):

The browser uses the name property of an element. So if you want to check if "adjustBtn'. $item_id.'" is set, try changing your code to:

```
if (isset($_POST["adjustBtn". $item_id]) {
```

edit: adjusted quotes

Comment: remove single quotes. `if(isset($_POST['adjustBtn'.$item_id])){`